# Set progress bar value according to the unknown length of text file

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

I currently have a program which reads from a text file and then writes to a database after each line it reads, the size of the text file is undetermined, some days the file could be more or less lines than other days.

I already have a swing worker that executes my functions so my progress bar works but right now I just have `setIndeterminate` to `true` so the user knows something is being done just not the actual progress.

Is there a way I can increment the progress bar after each line is read, but have it not reach 100 too early or too late, preferably without reading the the text file entirely before hand. Thanks, Beef.

Comment: When you say that the size of the text file is always changing, do you mean it is changing *while you are reading it* ?

Comment: @S.L.Barth no sorry, I just mean some days the file could be around 400 lines or on other days it could be 500, I just mean the file changes but prior to running it, it will never changing during run time

Comment: If the file length won't change during runtime, then it's effectively static. Just determine the length of the file, and periodically update the progress bar to *amount_read/file_length*.

Comment: @PatrickPerini in order to get the length of the file though that would require me to read the entire file twice, once just to get length, and then again while running the tasks progress that I want to monitor, which I wanted to try to avoid due to performance of my program

Comment: @Beef - The file size is stored as metadata, so reading the entire file isn't necessary to find it, just ask the OS what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [File.length()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) to determine the file size. Then keep track of the number of bytes read to determine the progress.

Answer (score 2):

If the file size is known before you are starting to read it you can read it line-by-line and count the percentage after every line: count the number of bytes in each line and devide it by the total number of bytes (i.e. `file.length()`).

Comment: Counting the number of lines seems unneccessary, since you all you really need is the amount of progress through the entire file (so `bytes read / total bytes`).

Comment: @BrendanLong so I did the calculation for total bytes / 1024 to get kb, but I cant find a good example of `CountingInputStream` in order to see how to use it

Comment: @Beef - When you're reading your file, do this: `CountingInputStream fileInput = new CountingInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(yourFile)));`, then whenever you want to know how many bytes you've read, call `fileInput.getByteCount()`. Note that you'll need to put [commons-io.jar](https://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi) in your class path.

Comment: @BrendanLong when editing my class path does that mean I would have to edit the class path on any computers used to run the .JAR version of this program?

Comment: @Beef Either this or add the jar on the java command line used to start your application

Comment: @Beef - Probably. Generally you'd put it in `lib/main` and then run with `java -cp lib/main/*:. YourMainClass`. If this is too much work, I doubt the `CountingInputStream` would be hard to implement yourself (just have a count variable that increments every time you read something from the underlying stream).

Comment: @BrendanLong alright, this is my first time making a program with the intention of running it on other machines, so I dont exactly know whats required to do so, Ill just try to implement the counting myself

Comment: @BrendanLong so right now I get the length of the file divide it by 1024 set the maximum of the progress bar to that value, and then every time I read a line I get the size of the line and divide it by 1024 and then update the progress bar equal to its current value plus the length of that line read divided by 1024, does this seem like the right direction?

Comment: @Beef - Sounds like it should work. You may want to add 1 byte at the end for the `\n` (or 2 for `\r\n`), but I doubt that changes the result enough to bother a user. Oh.. and I don't think the division by 1024 is necessary (since you're just comparing one number to another, as long as the units are the same it should be fine).

Answer (score 1):

and wrap output to the GUI (in your case the `Progress` from the `JProgressBar`) to the `invokeLater()`, because you are pretty out of the EDT, more in [Concurency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

To determine the file size is easy using `java.io.File` so the problem here is to get the size in bytes actually read for a simple progress bar two possibilities come to mind:

1. Estimation: Assume 1 Character = 1 Byte (or 1 Character = 2 Byte if your file is UTF-16,...). The 1 Byte guess will have you underestimate your actual size read so you will have a  jump of the bar at the end depending on how many multi byte characters are in your file.
2. Calculate: Recode the characters read to a byte array using the files character encoding and take the length of the encoded array.
3. Count: As proposed by Brendan in the comments below, use a `CountingInputStream` (in correct order after Buffering) to count the bytes actually read.

Nr. 2. seems unneccessary overhead for this case to me so I think I'd stick to Nr. 1 or Nr. 3

Comment: You could wrap the `InputStream` in a [`CountingInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html)

Comment: @Brendan Hey that's a good one, thanks! If I only knew that before my last project ;) It'l save me time in the future though :)

Comment: The Commons libraries are my favorite part of Java :D

Comment: But keep in mind that when using `CountingInputStream` together with a `BufferedReader` the count will be approximately.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the order? `new CountingInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(whatever))` would be correct, but `new BufferedInputStream(newCountingInputStream(whatever))` would be approximate.

Comment: @Brendan Yes I think so :) and `BufferedReader` will not be correct. I'll check that the next couple of days. I have do create an index of new line positions in a 4 GB CSV-File :D

Answer (score 0):

You can have in your app something like this image :)

[image: circle progress bar]